# How to detect scroll direction without actually scrolling the scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

How do i detect scroll direction / touch direction without actually scrolling on mobile and desktop?

I am currently using the below, but as we know this doesn't work on mobile.

```
window.onwheel = e => {
  if(e.deltaY >= 0){ //down

  } else { //up

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using touchstart and touchmove events. Here is an example:

```
let startY;

window.addEventListener('touchstart', e => {
  startY = e.touches[0].clientY;
});

window.addEventListener('touchmove', e => {
  const deltaY = e.touches[0].clientY - startY;

  if (deltaY >= 0) {
    // Downward scroll/touch direction
  } else {
    // Upward scroll/touch direction
  }
});
```

However, you might have to adjust the sensitivity of the touch movement threshold for it to work.

Comment: Hi , thanks for this - I tried adding this but it does not fire,  is this because it is waiting for the page to scroll and because it isn't scrolling it doesnt fire?

Comment: The code as far as I can tell seem to be fine. Can you double check for conflicting code, syntax errors, or the way the code is being implemented in your project? Some devices or browsers might actually put restrictions, but if not, the code might be conflicting with other javasript code

Comment: I will have a look, strangely it works in chromes fake mobile on swipe but not on actual mobile hmm

Comment: Yeah i can't get it to work on mobile, only the emulator picks up the swipes, how strange

Answer (score 0):

Resolved - I had this inside of an intersection observer and it turns out it wasn't detecting the element because the threshold was too high.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).